Caption is ignored when using as_raster function
Is there a way to include set_caption in a flextable object when you are adding it to a ggplot plot? In the following example, the caption "Table of iris" is dropped using flextable::as_raster():
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(grid)

# create inset table
table <- head(iris)[,1:3] %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  set_caption(paste0("Table of iris")) %>% 
  flextable::as_raster()

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point()

ggdraw(p) + 
  draw_plot(grid::rasterGrob(table), x = 1, y = 1, 
                                     hjust = 1, vjust = 1, 
                                     halign = 1, valign = 1,
                                     width = 0.5, height = 0.5)



You can achieve something similar staying with flextable by adding the text as header,
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(grid)

# create inset table
table <- head(iris)[,1:3] %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  #set_caption(paste0("Table of iris")) %>% 
  add_header_lines(paste0("Table of iris")) %>%
    
  flextable::as_raster()

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point()
p

ggdraw(p) + 
  draw_plot(grid::rasterGrob(table), x = 1, y = 1, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, halign = 1, valign = 1,
            width = 0.5,
            height = 0.5)


Thanks - that is certainly a much simpler approach although it does add a line above the header and uses different font (both of which can be changed but requires more code!)

Yeah custom formatting does usually require some extra code, but that was not what you were asking for. FWIW I would also not use the as_raster function to do this as it gives a deprecated warning and instead use gen_grob as recommended in the warning. But I offered a solution that got text to the top of your table by only changing 16 characters.

Here's an idea building on top of what BEVAN's answer proposed.
You can use flextable::add_header_lines, format it same as the caption using as_paragraph(..., center-align it using flextable::align, and remove the top line to make it look almost exactly like what you get from set_caption.
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(cowplot)
library(grid)


ft <- head(iris)[,1:3] %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  add_header_lines(as_paragraph(as_chunk(paste0("Table of iris"),
                                 props = fp_text_default(
                                            font.family = "San Serif", 
                                            font.size = 12)))) %>%
  align(i = 1, j = NULL, align = "center", part = "header") %>% 
  hline_top(part = "header", border = officer::fp_border(width = 0)) %>% 
  flextable::as_raster()


p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point()

ggdraw(p) + 
  draw_plot(grid::rasterGrob(ft), x = 1, y = 1, 
                                  hjust = 1, vjust = 1, 
                                  halign = 1, valign = 1,
                                  width = 0.5, height = 0.5)


Created on 2024-11-27 with reprex v2.0.2

If adding the caption via set_caption isn't required than an alternative would be to fake a caption using a textGrob where in the code below I use flextable::gen_grob (instead of the deprecated as_raster) to convert the flextable to a grob and patchwork::inset_element to add it to the ggplot:
library(patchwork)
library(flextable)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# create inset table
table <- head(iris)[, 1:3] |>
  flextable() |>
  set_caption("Table of Iris")

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()

p + inset_element(
  grid::grobTree(
    grid::textGrob(
      "Table of iris",
      y = unit(1, "npc") + unit(5, "pt"),
      vjust = 0,
      gp = grid::gpar(fontfamily = "serif", fontsize = 10)
    ),
    gen_grob(table, fit = "width")
  ),
  left = 0.6, bottom = .6,
  right = .975, top = .95,
  clip = FALSE
) +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )


And of course does the same approach work with cowplot:
library(cowplot)

grob <- grid::grobTree(
  grid::textGrob(
    "Table of iris",
    y = unit(1, "npc") + unit(5, "pt"),
    vjust = 0,
    gp = grid::gpar(fontfamily = "serif", fontsize = 10)
  ),
  gen_grob(table, fit = "width")
)

ggdraw(p) +
  draw_plot(grob,
    x = 1, y = .95, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, halign = 1, valign = 1,
    width = 0.5,
    height = 0.5
  )



thanks, really nice workaround. I ideally wanted to sick with cowplot due to other code downstream but I can switch over if needs be

I see. But if cowplot is the only constraint ... see my update.
